# (i'm close - i think) Python loop through list of subdomains with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop

starting with a base URL, I'm trying to have selenium loop through a short list of subdomains in csv format (ie: one column of 20 subdomains) and printing the html for each. I'm having trouble figuring it out. Thanks!

```
from selenium import selenium
import unittest, time, re, csv, logging

subds = csv.reader(open('listofsubdomains.txt', 'rb'))
for subd in subds:
        try:
            class Untitled(unittest.TestCase):
                def setUp(self):
                    self.verificationErrors = []
                    self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://www.sourcedomain.com")
                    self.selenium.start()

                def test_untitled(self):
                    sel = self.selenium
                    sel.open(subd[0])
                    html = sel.get_html_source()
                    print html

                def tearDown(self):
                    self.selenium.stop()
                    self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

            if __name__ == "__main__":
                unittest.main()

        except Exception, e:
            print>>sys.stderr, "Url % not processed: error (%s) % (url, e)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining the same function again and again in the body of the class. The class is completely created before `unittest.main()` starts, so only one test method will remain in the class.

Comment: Yeah, that's the same, but for classes. You create a lot of classes with the same name, so at the end (when you run `unittest.main()` ) only one remain.